# Confusion about initializers in C++ derived classes

Tags: c++

If I try to do this:

```
class Particle {
    protected:
    double redshift_;
};

class Nucleus: public Particle {
    Nucleus(double z): redshift_(z) {}
};
```

I get a compiler error saying `class ‘Nucleus’ does not have any field named ‘redshift_’`, but if I do this instead:

```
class Nucleus: public Particle {
    Nucleus(double z) { redshift_ = z; }
};
```

it works. Why is this?

Sorry for the (probably) dumb question -- it's the first time I try to write a derived class in C++.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405740/how-can-i-initialize-base-class-member-variables-in-derived-class-constructor

Comment: once the constructor of `Nucleus` is executed, the constructor for `Particle` has already run. Hence, `redshift_` already got default initialized and you cannot use the initializer list to initialize it

Comment: This is because in the second case, constructor of the Nucleus starts only after constructor of base class ends and redshift_ is created in scope, hence successful completion. When initialiser lists are used, redshift_ is still not created as base class's constructor is not yet called.