# OOP - abstract class types, initializing variables in base and derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Similar to: [How can I initialize base class member variables in derived class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405740/how-can-i-initialize-base-class-member-variables-in-derived-class-constructor), but I was wondering why if I have:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int val);
    virtual int get_val() = 0;
protected:
    int val;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int val, int extra);
    int get_val() = 0;
private:
    int extra;
};
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between doing this:

```
A::A(int val) : val(val) {}
```

and:

```
A::A(int val) {val = val;}
```

And also why, when I'm in the constructor for class B, I can't do:

```
B::B(int b, int extra) : A(b) {
    extra = extra;
}
```

But I can do:

```
B::B(int b, int extra) : A(b) {
    this->extra = extra;
}
```

or,

```
B::B(int b, int extra) : A(b), extra(extra){}
```

to store the value of extra in B. If I don't do those it's not stored. I'm very confused what's happening.

Comment: `extra = extra` assigns `extra` to itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering what is the difference between doing this:
>
> ```
> A::A(int val) : val(val) {}
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> A::A(int val) {val = val;}
> ```

The first is right and the second is wrong.

More precisely, the first one initialises the data member `A::val` with the value of the constructor parameter `val`, which is without any doubt precisely what you intend to do.

The second one, in contrast, does nothing with `A::val`, leaving it with an uninitialised value, which will later cause undefined behaviour as soon as you try to read from the data member. The `val = val;` line assigns the constructor parameter `val` to itself, which is completely meaningless.

The second one would be okayish if you used a different parameter name to disambiguate, for example:

```
A::A(int new_val) { val = new_val; }
```

It would also work fine if you did like in your own `this->extra = extra;` example:

```
A::A(int val) { this->val = val; }
```

In both cases, the compiler now knows that you mean `A::val`.

However, this form of constructor implementation is atypical in C++ and often a sign of a Java or C# programmer. It leaves `A::val` uninitialised for a moment and then assigns it a value. That just isn't very logical. Why not initialise it right away if you can? It also won't work with `const` members, with reference members or with data types that don't have default constructors or a way to assign something later.

By the way, this doesn't have anything to do with efficiency but only with correctness and readability.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what is the difference between doing this:
>
> `A::A(int val) : val(val) {}`
>
> and:
>
> `A::A(int val) {val = val;}`

No difference for primitive types. However, if val is a non-primitive type, e.g. std::string, Using the first way(initialization list) is more efficient. Think of

Method 1 is the same as:

```
string val(val);
```

Method 2 is the same as:

```
string val; //default initialize first;
val = val2; //assign val2 to val
```

That is, even if you do not provide anything in the initialization list, compiler will still call the default constructor to initialize it first before going into {} block. Since primitive types do not have constructors, using initialization list does not really improve the efficiency.

> And also why, when I'm in the constructor for class B, I can't do:
>
> `B::B(int b, int extra) : A(b) {`
>
> `extra = extra;`
>
> `}`

Similar to the explanation above. Inside the {}, "extra" will be defined, and local object overshadow the data member. However, there is no harm in choosing a different parameter name.

Comment: *"No difference for primitive types."* - No, `val = val;` in that constructor is self-assignment and will later cause undefined behaviour when an attempt is made to read `A::val`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the correction! I was focusing on the difference between with and without the initialization list. And I also touched this point in the second part of my answer.