# Constructor for derived class that assigns values to both base class and derived class data members

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

The base class has a constructor and 2 public member data, while the derived class has a constructor and 1 private member data. I would like the derived class to have a constructor which assigns values to its data as well as the base class's data. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in C++ than simply using the `this` pointer?

Here's what I have:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
  int A {5};
  int B {10};
  Base() {}
  Base(int A_, int B_) : A(A_), B(B_) {} 
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  int C {15};
  Derived(int C_) : C(C_) {}
  Derived(int C_, int A_, int B_) {
    C = C_;
    this->A = A_;
    this->B = B_;
  }
};
```

Here's something what I would like in the derived class (because it would be more general I think, but I am uncertain about the appropriate syntax to use):

```
Derived(int C_, VariableArguments ... base_args) {
    C = C_;
    Base(base_args ...)
  }
```

Comment: Just change `Derived(int C_, int A_, int B_)` to `Derived(int C_, int A_, int B_): Base(A_, B_), C(C_)`. Also see [How can I initialize base class member variables in derived class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405740/how-can-i-initialize-base-class-member-variables-in-derived-class-constructor)

Comment: This code has a lot of bugs.  Enable your compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.  One of the warnings would have answered this very question (and some compilers would have even provided a suggestion).

Comment: Also, if it is not clear from my first comment, use **member initializer list** instead of assignment inside ctor body.

Comment: @Eljay I fixed the bugs. Not sure which warnings you are referring to, though. `g++ -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused`

Comment: Fundamental principle: each class is responsible for its own members. `Derived` shouldn't try to initialize base class members; that's the job of the base class's constructor. Also, the derived class **can't** initialize base class members; in the code in the question the default constructor for `Base` **initializes** the members of `Base`, and then the constructor for `Derived` **assigns** new values to them.